# Android, Super not called exception error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, MyFirst fragment and MySecond fragment. MySecond fragment extends from MyFirst fragment.

classed are like this:

```
public class MyFirstFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ...                
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ...
            // Check view and map, request to recreate if each of them is null
            if(MyFirstFragment.this.getView() == null  ||  googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.my_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

public class MySecondFragment extends MyFirstFragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        }
    }
```

My problem is `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);` in onActivityCreated() method of MySecondFragment calls its super. Since I want to hide functionality of this method in super class (Which is not useful for this fragment) I have added onActivityCreated() method in MySecondFragment.

The problem is if I remove this line then I have run-time error that throws "SuperNotCalledException".

What you think? seems I have to extend Fragment class instead of extending MyFirstFragment.
I have some variables in MyFirstFragment that I need them in MySecondFragment.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to remove that line? Does it cause any trouble?

Comment: He wants to hide the functionality inside the parent fragment. Try removing the whole method onActivityCreated from MySecondFragment.

Comment: @Caner, As you can see there is a Toast message in super method. Then displays in second fragment which should not display. That Toast message belongs to first fragment not second one.

Comment: Debug. Put a breakpoint in SecondFragment's onActivityCreated, be 100% sure its hitting that line

Comment: If you override, you need to call super(). For you, super() comes from 1st Fragment. Why do you NOT expect the Toast?

Comment: You probably just messed up your hierarchy. Chances are good that you just need to turn around the inheritance hierary (MyFirstFragment extends MySecondFragment). If this does not work for you you probably need another layer of abstraction from which both Fragments extend.

Comment: Up vote just because you mentioned that removing this line super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState) causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a new Function `testFunction(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in your `MyFirstFragment` in which call `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`

And in your `MySecondFragment`'s `onActivityCreated` call this `testFunction(Bundle savedInstanceState)` rather than `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`
i.e.

in `MyFirstFragment`

```
testFunction(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

in `MySecondFragment`

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.testFunction(savedInstanceState);
...
}
```

i don't clearly understand your basic requirment to bypass the `MyFirstFragment`'s `onActivityCreated` but you can do this way.

Comment: Works fine, nice solution although I'm not sure is a clean way. But works, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the Fragment's implementation regardless. If you don't want to call MyFirstFragment's implementation there's a few solutions:

1. The cleanest one, give MyFirstFragment  and MySecondFragment a common ancestor, which will be pretty much MyFirstFragment , except for onActivityCreated(). Both activities will inherit directly from it.
2. call super, but add a variable to the bundle to let MyFirstFragment  know that its implementation is not to be called this time.
3. Just extend Fragment in MySecondFragment

Answer (score -1):

You should always call the super method. Just set the variables you need in the MySecondFragment.onActivityCreated() method and use them afterwards. To hide functionality you can always check the calling object class but this goes against the OOP inheritance principles.

Comment: but it IS calling super. SecondFragment calls to super.onActivityCreated, which is FirstFragment's onActivityCreated, which in turn also calls super.onActivityCreated, which goes up to the Fragment.

Comment: As far as I can understand, the OP does not want to call super.onActivityCreated(), because of some code that should not be run for MySecondFragment.onActivityCreated(). So he either needs to run the code only if the calling object's class is MyFirstFragment, or as mick88 pointed out, the best solution is to have both MyFirstFragment and MySecondFragment inherit a common abstract ancestor that has the common code in his onActivityCreated() and the subclasses should implement their specific code in their onActivityCreated() methods